# Problems scraping a website with a preloader

Tags: python, web, beautifulsoup, scrapy, screen-scraping

I'm trying to **scrape** this website

https://www.neds.com.au/sports/esports

I'm using scrapy to do it but any attempt i make only grabs the preloader page. Am i just using the wrong tools?

Comment: This is why they have the preloader page ;) Libraries such as scrapy typically don't execute any javascript so won't load in any content, meaning you just get the raw html for the preloader page

Comment: You will need to either use splash-scrapy or selenium scrapy to do this, as a result of what Luke says.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I appreciate it.

Comment: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/dynamic-content.html

Answer (score 1):

Whatever tool you end up using, it has to monitor DOM changes and only start the actual scraping when DOM is stable (content no longer changes for an arbitrary amount of time).

One such tool is the open source browser extension https://github.com/get-set-fetch/extension . It scrapes based on CSS selectors and has a "Stability Timeout" option.

From the docs: Stability Timeout - Considers the page loaded and ready to be scraped when there are no more DOM changes within the specified amount of time (milliseconds). Only applies to html resources. Useful for bypassing preloader content.

Disclaimer: I'm the extension author.